# How to override boolean handleUnattended()

Tags: java, install4j

I'm creating an installer with latest Install4J (6.x)

There I have added a "Configurable form" with a "Text field"-component to get a value from user.

[image]

The problem is I want to enable the -q (unattended mode) for the installer. As far as I understand I have to override the handleUnattended method for this screen/form so I can get the value from a installer-parameter like -Vport=1337 and use it in the "Write properties to file"-action.

My question is, where can I override this method? I checked the whole application where I can code this override-method but can't find something useful even in the official docs.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding handleUnattended() is only possible for custom screens that you develop with the API.

You can just add a "Run script" action and set its condition expression to `context.isUnattended()` and add the unattended logic there.